# find inside Python subprocess returns 1

Tags: python, find

I need to search the contents of a directory with the following GNU `find` command:

> find *path* -type f -name *file1* -o -name *file2* -o -name *file3*

When I execute this command in my Linux shell, the `find` command returns with exit code 0. When I execute the same command within a subprocess call, the `find` command returns exit code 1:

```
import subprocess  
import shlex  
findcmd = "/depot/findutils/bin/find /remote/scratch/results -type f -name 'QUEUED' -o -name 'run.pid' -o -name 'PID'"
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(findcmd))
except subprocess.CalledProcessError, cpe:
    print cpe.output
    raise cpe
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./getaverages.py", line 63, in <module>
    raise cpe
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/depot/findutils/bin/find', '/remote/scratch/results', '-type', 'f', '-name', 'QUEUED', '-o', '-name', 'run.pid', '-o', '-name', 'PID']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

The strange part is that the `CalledProcessError` object output atribute has exactly the same output that I get when I run `find` in the Linux shell (the returned output has about 15K lines). I also tried setting *bufsize=-1* but that didn't help.

Any suggestion for understanding this behavior?

I'm using Python 2.7.2 and `find` version is 4.2.20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in the middle of the 15K output I missed the following lines:

```
/depot/findutils/bin/find: /remote/scratch/results/tmp.na.8Em5fZ: No such file or directory
/depot/findutils/bin/find: /remote/scratch/results/tmp.na.k6iHJA: No such file or directory
/depot/findutils/bin/find: /remote/scratch/results/tmp.na.ZPe2TC: No such file or directory
```

It turns out that the *path* I'm searching contains simulation results and it is being deleted regularly for files older than 3 days. It seems that when the delete happens when `find` is being executed is the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the problem you have found, for such a simple thing you are trying to achieve, I wouldn't *shell-out*, use `os.walk` instead:

```
import os, os.path
search = 'file1 file2 file3'.split()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/path'):
  for f in filter(lambda x: x in search, files):
    # do something here
    fn = os.path.join(root, f)
    print 'FOUND', fn
```

Comment: I'm always more inclined to use find (or generally GNU/Linux commands) because: 1) Python code becomes more compact, 2) It's generally easier for me to test the input/output in the shell, rather than isolate input/output inside a larger Python program, 3) execution seems faster (although this is more an impression than fact-based). Nevertheless, thanks for the tip.

Comment: If that is how you feel, why the heck don't you use shell scripting then?

Comment: I meant using some good shell tools inside Python scripts vs doing everything inside Python.

Comment: Whatever scratches your itch... If you're really concerned about speed, however, you could use multi-threading in python to accelerate things. E.g. one thread does the walking (the producer) and the other threads the processing (consumers). As an added benefit, it will work cross-platform, since even different *NIX platforms have incompatible `find` implementations.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [plumbum](http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), the task would be as simple as:

```
from plumbum.cmd import find
cmd = find['/remote/scratch/results']['-type', 'f']['-name','QUEUED']['-o']['-name', 'run.pid']['-o']['-name', 'PID']
cmd() # run it
```

You don't need to worry about escaping, which I'm going to guess is the cause of your trouble.